# function is not invoking in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell what is problem in the following code... when i run the program in browser a blank white screen appears... I don't know why its not working... I am not very sure with the syntax...
I don't want to invoke the function by any events.. i just want to write a function and invoke it by a manual call...

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function salin()
            {
                var sal = prompt("Enter your current salary - ","");
                var in = prompt("Enter the increment % - ","");

                sal = parseInt(sal);
                in = parseInt(in);

                var nsal = sal +( sal*(in /100));

                alert("Your new salary is - " + nsal);
            }

         salin();
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console.?

Comment: no... i don't see any error

Comment: You must be getting error: "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in",

Comment: `in` is reserved keyword in java-script so, your variable name cannot be `in`

Comment: @trex1999 Where exactly are you looking? In Firefox you get `SyntaxError: missing variable name`.

Comment: Thanks for every help guyzz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be in this line `in = parseInt(in);`

[**in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is a reserved keyword in javascript which is use to return a boolean value. Replace it with a different variable name

Answer (score 3):

I have created this fiddle..

Its working. You were using reserved javascript keyword

```
function salin()
            {
                var sal = prompt("Enter your current salary - ","");
                var values = prompt("Enter the increment % - ","");

                sal = parseInt(sal);
                values = parseInt(values);

                var nsal = sal +( sal*(values /100));

                alert("Your new salary is - " + nsal);
            }

         salin();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abdur_rehman26/7L9uvxon/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function salin()
        {

                            var sal = prompt("Enter your current salary - ","");
            var income = prompt("Enter the increment % - ","");

            sal = parseInt(sal);
            income = parseInt(income);

            var nsal = sal +( sal*(income /100));

            return "Your new salary is - " + nsal;
        }

     alert(salin());
```

Notice I added `return` and put the `alert()` on the function call. I also changed "in" to "income"

Comment: Good answers don’t just dump “working” code. Good answers explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

'in' is a reserved keyword. change that to some other variable name

```
       <body>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function salin()
        {
            var sal = prompt("Enter your current salary - ","");
            var in1 = prompt("Enter the increment % - ","");

            sal = parseInt(sal);
            in1 = parseInt(in1);

            var nsal = sal +( sal*(in1 /100));

            alert("Your new salary is - " + nsal);
        }

     salin();
  </script>



</body>
```